# Laravel routes doesn't work other than '/' after change AllowOverride

Tags: laravel, xampp

after i create project with laravel 7.25 (this is the first time i use this version, i used 7.20 on the last project ) i create route in web.php file on routes folder

```
Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/test', function () {
    dd("k");
});
```

when i tried to run them, only "/" that work and the "/test" is not found 404, but it works on my friends device, i use xampp, here's the apache
httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Why doesn't the second route work? Is there an error or something? Please provide more info...

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, it only show not found 404

Comment: When you run `php artisan route:list` in your console, is there `/test` route ?

Comment: yes, and the action is closure

Answer (score 0):

Depending on our conversation in the comments, I think the problem is that your route function doesn't have the `return` value, hence it returns empty page or `404`. Try to change your route to this:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return dd("k");
});
```

Read more about routes on [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing),

Comment: Hmm, not sure then what could be the problem. Are these two the only routes that you defined in your routes file?

Comment: no, here they are : `Route::get('/schedule', 'ControllerSchedule@index')->name('indexschedule');

Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return dd("k");
});
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
`